# Location by IP address indoors

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, wifi, latitude-longitude

What methods does Google  use to match IP addresses to approximate location inside a building using wifi or service-provider?

Comment: Every ISP is assigned a bunch of IP addresses and the information about the ISP location is also publically available (whois), so it's a simple matter of reverse lookup. Note, IP address only give you the general area not the exact location (unlike what CSI tells you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual location identification method is abstracted away. Developers are to only concern themselves with the source.

The NETWORK_PROVIDER source uses the IP Address and Cellular triangulation to identify the user's location.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER

Answer (score 2):

Also the method getLastKnownLocation(best) that provides the LocationManager can be used, as GPS won't work indoors. It is not accurate, but it will give a location of a big area.